# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray''

Tags: tensorflow

When I tried to execute the below code

```
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    sess.run(training_step, feed_dict={x:train_x,y:train_y})
```

the following error is raised:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081403/unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray-error-in-tensorflow

Comment: Also, in fututre try to add more context to your question for example in which line are you getting the error and what values do the variables take.